# set jms type to a message sent by gatling

Tags: jms, gatling

Does gatling DSL support setting jms type for outgoing message?

`.property("JMSType", jmsType)` doesn't seem to be the correct answer as it sets property rather than header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. But it should be pretty easy to implement. Contributions welcome :)

Comment: For the reference: [Issue](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/2967) has been created.